# How to open database format file

Tags: database

I got some database file, but the format like this :

[image]

Anyone know which database software able to open those db format ? Thanks

Comment: its Berkeley DB , check this link for more info [BerkeleyDB](http://www.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/help/BerkeleyDB/ref/env/region.html) as for a tool check this link [oracle berkeleydb](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/berkeleydb/downloads/index.html)